# Convert $50!$ to product of the powers of respective prime numbers ? (without direct calculation )

Tags: number-theory

I was solving a problem & stumbled across this idea.Can we convert factorial products in to "product of the powers of those respective prime numbers" without direct calculation & using some other concepts.In case of smaller factorials direct method is fine but its not in case of bigger factorials like $50!$,$100!$,etc. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the formula
$$v_p(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$
(this is really a finite sum) for the number of times $p$ divides $n!$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Isn't it [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula)?

Comment: yeah its legendre's formulae not lagrange's.